# Spreading Redux Actions does not work in mapDispatchToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

My mapDispatchToProps works like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  getCourts: () => dispatch(courtActions.getCourts()),
  selectStyle: style => dispatch(courtActions.selectStyle(style)),
  selectPoint: index => dispatch(courtActions.selectPoint(index)),
  sortPoints: sort => dispatch(courtActions.sortPoints(sort))
});
```

I want to write it like:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
      ...courtActions,
});
```

but when I do that none of my actions work (they dont get dispatched). I'm sure this is something obvious. But what is going on here?

Here is the actions file:

```
export const getCourts = () => dispatch =>
  axios
    .get("/courts")
    .then(response => dispatch({ type: GET_COURTS, payload: response.data }));

export const selectStyle = style => ({ type: SELECT_STYLE, payload: style });

export const sortPoints = type => ({ type: SORT_POINTS, payload: type });

export const selectPoint = index => ({ type: SELECT_POINT, payload: index });

export default {
  getCourts,
  selectStyle,
  sortPoints,
  selectPoint
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mapDispatchToProps` takes an object too, which you can use instead of defining a function as `mapDispatchToProps` which would need to return functions that use dispatch.

According to the docs:

> If an object is passed, each function inside it is assumed to be a
>   Redux action creator. An object with the same function names, but with
>   every action creator wrapped into a dispatch call so they may be
>   invoked directly, will be merged into the component’s props.

Example

```
const mapDispatchToProps = courtActions;
```

Or you can simply pass `courtActions` as the second parameter to connect like

```
connect(mapStateToProps, courtActions)(MyComponent);
```

Comment: Glad to have helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

as per my understanding mapDispatchToProps is function which takes dispatch as parameter and thats a dispatcher which dispatch massages to reducers. you cannot use like you want to use.